# Converting unix cli command to windows

Tags: command-line, unix, cmd.exe, openssl

I am using gethttpsforfree.com to get my cert. I am stuck on step 3. They want me to run a command but it's a unix command and I am on windows. The command is

```
PRIV_KEY=./account.key; echo -n "eyJub25jZSI6...cGRmIn0" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign $PRIV_KEY
```

Now this won't work on cmd ofcourse. But I am not that good on cli. The closest I have gotten to get it to work is

```
echo -n "eyJub25jZSI6...cGRmIn0" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign accout.key
```

The output comes but the site won't accept it. So I assume the | is the problem because it has different meanings on win/unix cli. So I need help converting that to cmd equivalant

Comment: As far as I know, the pipe (***`|`***) functions the same on the Unix'es and Windows. Maybe it would be easier to download [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), stand up a [Ubuntu VM](http://www.ubuntu.com/), and then execute the command in a Linux terminal. Otherwise, I would look at line endings as the culprit - `CR/LF` (Windows) versus `LF` (Linux).

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to install and boot up a vm on my super clean windows install just to run a command :/

Comment: @jww Pipe is effectively the same on Windows, but in CMD `echo` doesn't support `-n` and it doesn't remove quotes and trailing space like Unix shell. Put the desired characters `ey...n0` (NO newline) in a *file* with notepad then `openssl dgst ... <filename`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am not sure where the filename will be wrt the key file. So it will have both files? in what order? Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Doesn't really matter; CMD executes redirection(s) and removes it(them) from the commandline passed to the child program. (Unix shells do the same, but also word-split and glob the arguments, which CMD does not; for a C program, such as OpenSSL, the C runtime does this on Windows.) It is common to put redirection(s) at the end of the command if there is not a strong reason to do otherwise; this tends to be easier to read, and find, so I would suggest that (while noting it isn't required).